# is Yii::app()->name cached on yii?

Tags: php, yii

is Yii::app()->name cached on yii? Is it good to use it regularly? I decided to use a custom page title on my layout and i use it something like this on my controller.

```
$this->pageTitle = Yii::app()->name . ":" . $action
```

Comment: how does it make a difference above?

Comment: @itachi - they're asking since if it's being loaded on every page, there could be a performance penalty (e.g. if a new instance of Yii::app is instantiated everytime or something similar)

Answer (score 9):

It is not *cached* cached, but it's ok to use it as much as you want. From [the guide](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/basics.application):

> The application object is instantiated as a singleton by the entry script. The application singleton can be accessed at any place via Yii::app().

So the object is already there, and you are just accessing it to read the `name` property.

---

**Update**: To understand this better, let's trace [the application lifecycle](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/basics.application#application-life-cycle):

- entry script *index.php* creates the application, [with `Yii::createWebApplication`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/YiiBase#createWebApplication-detail).
- `Yii::createWebApplication` calls [`Yii::createApplication`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/YiiBase#createApplication-detail), which then creates a new CWebApplication object, meaning its **constructor** ([defined in parent CApplication](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CApplication#__construct-detail)) is called. **This constructor sets the application singleton object**:

  ```
  Yii::setApplication($this);
  ```

  And then it carries out the first 4 steps of the lifecycle, which are (from the application lifecycle [link above](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/basics.application#application-life-cycle)):

  1. Pre-initialize the application with [CApplication::preinit()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CApplication#preinit); i.e: `$this->preinit();`
  2. Set up the class autoloader and error handling; i.e [`$this->initSystemHandlers();`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CApplication#initSystemHandlers-detail)
  3. Register core application components; i.e [`$this->registerCoreComponents();`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CApplication#registerCoreComponents-detail)
  4. Load application configuration; i.e [`$this->configure($config);`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CModule#configure-detail). This sets the `name`.
  5. Attach behaviors; i.e [`$this->attachBehaviors($this->behaviors);`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CComponent#attachBehaviors-detail)
     Load static application components; i.e [`$this->preloadComponents();`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CModule#preloadComponents-detail)
     Initialize the application with `CApplication::init();` i.e [`$this->init();`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CWebApplication#init-detail)

  The application **object** that was created is returned by `createApplication` to `createWebApplication`.
- This same **object** is then used to call the [`run()` method](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CApplication#run-detail) in the entry script:

  ```
  Yii::createWebApplication($config)->run();
  ```

  The `run` method then carries out the rest of the lifecycle:

  1. (6) Raise an `onBeginRequest` event; i.e: `$this->onBeginRequest(new CEvent($this));`
  2. (7) Process the user request (with [`$this->processRequest();`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CWebApplication#processRequest-detail)):

     - Collect information about the request;
     - Create a controller;
     - Run the controller;

       So when your controller is being run, if you call `Yii::app()` the **same object** that was created in `createApplication` and set in the constructor, is used, therefore no new object is created, and the property is just fetched from the already existing object.
  3. (8) Raise an `onEndRequest` event; i.e: `$this->onEndRequest(new CEvent($this));`

Comment: And it's read in as part of your config, so it doesn't add any load time :-)

Comment: wpleet see my update, i have tried to explain things a little more, now it should be quite clear to you that there is not much extra work done in fetching the app name, if you have doubts do comment. Also as @acorncom has mentioned, when config is read in, the name is set.

Answer (score 0):

> it good to use it regularly?

No, it is not good, because if someday you will need to modify your app name, it will be problem for you to change it in every controller. I guess the better way is to redeclare `Yii::$app->name` directly in `layout`.

At the begiging of your layout, probably in `views/layout/main.php` add

```
Yii::$app->name = Yii::$app->name . ':' . Yii::$app->getView()->id;
```